# How to avoid repetitive code in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, generalization

I'm using Qt 5.4.1.

I'm currently setting up some buttons in QML. I want similar state behaviours for some of the buttons - how to do I avoid having large chunks of very similar code repeated through the QML?

```
Rectangle {
        id: songFilterButton

        x: 0; width: 80
        y: 0; height: 60

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Songs"
        }

        state: "on"; states: [
            State {
                name: "on"
                PropertyChanges{ target: songFilterButton; color: "steelblue" }
            },
            State {
                name: "on"
                PropertyChanges{ target: songFilterButton; color: "white" }
            }
        ]

        MouseArea { id: region; anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: songFilterButton.toggle() }

        function toggle() {
            if(state == "on") { state = "off" } else { state = "on" }
        }
    }
```

That would be quite a bit of code to repeat for several buttons, and each time I add to a button functionality (like sending signals to C++ and other behaviours), I would have to do it multiple times...

I've read over the link provided by MrEricSir and created a HKRadioButton.qml with the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    property string text: label.text

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    state: "on"; states: [
        State {
            name: "on"
            PropertyChanges{ target: songFilterButton; color: "steelblue" }
        },
        State {
            name: "off"
            PropertyChanges{ target: songFilterButton; color: "white" }
        }
    ]

    MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: parent.toggle() }

    function toggle() {
        if(state == "on") { state = "off" } else { state = "on" }
    }
}
```

In my main QML file, I have

```
HKRadioButton {
        id: songFilterButton

        x: 0; width: 80
        y: 0; height: 60

        text: "Songs"
    }
```

I get the behaviour (changing state), but not the text...

Comment: You simply define new QML types by putting them into separate files. More info is here in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-topic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own components. You can create a component "in place" and then right-click on the component's root object -> Refactoring -> Move component into separate file. For example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: button
    ...
}
```

After you move that to a Button.qml, you can just use:

```
Button {
    ...
}
```

Use "inline" components:

```
Component {
    id: button
    Rectangle {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can use `button` with a `Loader` or for dynamic instantiation using `button.createObject(parentItem)`

As the other answer noted, if you want to create properties for your component which refer to some sub-object properties, use an alias property, helps avoid unnecessary bindings.

```
Rectangle {
    property string text

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: parent.text // this is what you want
    }
    ...
}
```

But that would introduce a needless binding, you can use an `alias` to directly reference the label's `text` from the root component property as folibis suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
property string text: label.text
```

to

```
property alias text: label.text
```

Now you just assign `label`.`text` to own property `HKRadioButton`.`text` but it should be just the opposite action.