# QT 5.12 Prototype Cycle, the last non repeated element error M303

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am getting this error/mal practice popup. I am not sure how to fix/ it. I've looked on QT and I still don't quite understand their explanation. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909050/how-to-avoid-repetitive-code-in-qml) this issue on another post, but I am still not sure what they are saying. It occurs even wherever I create a Checkbox.

[image: ****]

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `QtQuick 2.* as QtQuick` and then use the checkbox as `QtQuick.Checkbox`